# проблема с OnBecame*

Tags: c#, unity3d

Проблема в том, что имею объект (группа), в котором лежат части (с `MeshRenderer`), а у самой группы его нет, так как он там и не нужен в принципе, так-как части и есть собранный объект:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но этот код отказывается работать:

```
public class B : MonoBehaviour {
    bool t = false;
    void Update() {
        if (t) {
            print(1);
        }
    }
    void OnBecameVisible() {
        t = true;
    }

    void OnBecameInvisible() {
        t = false;
    }
}
```

Но как только я вешаю `MeshRenderer` на `Group`, начинает работать.
Почему так происходит?
Мне `MeshRenderer` не нужен на `Group`, он там бесполезен в принципе - это обычная группа, чтобы все лежало вместе и можно было передвинуть все части.

Как быть?

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите документацию по [OnBecameVisible](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnBecameVisible.html):

> Этот метод вызывается у всех скриптов, которые прикреплены к объектам, на которых есть Renderer.

Иными словами, то, на что вы жалуетесь - документированное поведение метода. Без наличия компонента Renderer юнити будет сложно определить "форму" объекта на сцене. А не зная форму, юнити не может понять попадает ли объект в камеру. Они могли бы сделать внутри механизм, который пробегался бы по дочерним элементам и каким-то образом, на основе дочерних Renderer прикидывал форму, но есть подозрение, что это было бы сильно затратно по ресурсам.

Выходов из вашей ситуации может быть несколько:

1. Вешать скрипт на дочерние элементы, вместо родительской группы
2. Написать скрипт, в котором вы будете задавать некоторый радиус объекта и вручную проверять попадает ли объект в указанную камеру, без методов а ля `OnBecomeVisible`

Comment: Я выбираю вариант 3. Накидываю пустой `MeshRenderer`, делаю у него размер 0 и выставляю все параметры в `off`. Все работает и ничего не жрет. Ибо выхода нет, писать велосипед, нет смысла.